# Finding if common sub-string exists with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I want to find if there is a sub-string of the string "chef" but in order in another given string with length > 1.

So basically we want strings **ch, he, ef, che, hef** or **chef** to exist in the given string. 

Ex:

1> k**ef**aa 
Here we have **ef** which is part of **''chef''** so it is a valid string. 
2> fhlasek 
Here we have **fh** which characters exist in **'chef'** but the sequence is incorrect so it is invalid.

I have this code that works but here adding substrings manually is easy as the string **'chef'** has quite fewer possibilities but I want a code that will work for any given string.

```
import re
pattern = r"(ch|he|ef|che|hef|chef)"
s = input()
res = re.search(pattern, s)
if bool(res):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

P.S. Im sorry if this question was already asked and solved, I was unable to find it. 
Thank You.

Comment: You could just make each character optional with `?` and then check if the string is not empty.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer But then the string 'fhlasek' will be counted as valid too. And we don't need that.

Comment: If you only _want to find **if** there is a sub-string_, then checking the substrings with length greater than 2 is pointless.

Comment: @Armali Yes, but it is mentioned to make sure that we don't match just a common letter.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Python:

```
def test(txt, string):
    le = len(txt)
    fragments = [txt[i:j] for i in range(le) for j in range(i+1, le+1) if j-i>1]
    # 'chef' --> ['ch', 'che', 'chef', 'he', 'hef', 'ef']

    for fragment in fragments: 
        if fragment in string: return 'YES';
    return 'NO' 

print(test("chef", "ch"))     # YES
print(test("chef", "che"))    # YES
print(test("chef", "c"))      # NO
print(test("chef", "fh"))     # NO
print(test("chef", "kefaa"))  # YES
```

If you need regexp here you go:

```
import re

def get_reg(txt,s):
    le = len(txt)
    fragments = [txt[i:j] for i in range(le) for j in range(i+1, le+1) if j-i>1]
    return bool(re.search("|".join(fragments),s))
    # 'chef' --> 'ch|che|chef|he|hef|ef'

print(get_reg("chef","ch"))    # True
print(get_reg("chef","che"))   # True
print(get_reg("chef","c"))     # False
print(get_reg("chef","fh"))    # False
print(get_reg("chef","kefaa")) # True
```

Recurse:

```
import re

def get_framgents(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        fragments.append(word[:len(word)-i])
    if len(word)>0:
        get_framgents(word[1:])
        
word = 'chef'
fragments = []
get_framgents(word)             # --> ['chef','che','ch','hef','he','ef']
fragments = '|'.join(fragments) # --> 'chef|che|ch|hef|he|ef'

print(bool(re.search(fragments, "ch")))    # True
print(bool(re.search(fragments, "che")))   # True  
print(bool(re.search(fragments, "c")))     # False
print(bool(re.search(fragments, "fh")))    # False
print(bool(re.search(fragments, "kaeef"))) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the word and build a custom regex, then use that regex in your `search`:

```
from re import search, compile

word = "chef"
s = input()

pattern = []
for i in range(len(word) - 1):
    pattern.append(word[i] + word[i+1])
pattern = compile("|".join(pattern))

if bool(search(pattern, s)):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: But it gets only three substrings `ch|he|ef`

Comment: Think of it this way: if a word contains the substring hef, then it would also contain the substrings, he and ef. Also see [Armali's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489118/finding-if-common-sub-string-exists-with-regex/68489395?noredirect=1#comment121044268_68489118) above.